# How can I extract the duration of a GIF animation from a file in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, animated-gif

I found this article http://web.archive.org/web/20130820015012/http://madskristensen.net/post/Examine-animated-Gife28099s-in-C.aspx (very helpful).

Unfortunately, our favorite hobbled race horse, UWP, does not include the required APIs.

I am working on a slide show app and would like to allow the user to advance an image with a set timing, except if it is an animated GIF, then I want to show the full animation once...

So, where can I extract the duration of the complete GIF animation, using the UWP on board tools?

Comment: Try to use `XamlAnimatedGif ` nuget. I think it contains logic for getting duration.

Comment: Hi Mykyta, I would love to, but I have found some stability and performance issues with that nuget. Thomas, the author, recommended to me to use the on-board methods... But UR right, I might have to go through his code and see how he access the delay parameter per frame...